# How to use csrf (csrftoken) cookie session with django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Tags: django, oauth, token, csrf

I have setup django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 to retrieve a token from django using facebook provider :

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&backend=facebook&token=<facebook_token> https://dev.myapp.com/api/auth/convert-token
```

Everytime i do a request to my app, i add the token to the header :

```
curl -i https://dev.myapp.com/api/users -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken123"
```

Everything works so far

I am using ReactJs as frontend and do the above request from reactjs:

```
axios.post("https://dev.myapp.com/api/auth/convert-token", postData).then(res => {console.log(res);}
```

If the user closes the windows, he gets logged out as he does not have access to the token anymore, and if he goes back to my application, he has to login again.

I would like to be able to use browser cookie to save the token i get from django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 and secure it with csrf protection to let the user access to my app without to click on "login" again and again

I dont know how to do it and i dont know if it is possible?

How should I setup django-rest-framework-social-oauth2, to get the csrftoken and use it for each API call ?

The only solution I have got is to create another view that will create the csrftoken

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.template.context_processors import csrf

 def my_view(request):
     c = {}
     c.update(csrf(request))
     data='my test'
     # ... view code here
     return Response(data, c)
```

This view return the csrftoken cookie

But I would like to get this csrftoken cookie in meantime that i get the oauth2 token.

How can I do that?
Do you have some example? some doc? what is the best way to do it ?

If it is not possible, do you know any alternative to be able to let the user access to my app without to click on "login" everytime?

Thank you for your answers